# Why this code breaks when optimizations are on?

Tags: c, gcc

Turning optimizations on break this code where the map is set. It's being set to NULL instead of the correct values. Am I invoking undefined behavior without knowing?

Valgrind does not report any invalid read/write. I'm using gcc (Debian 4.8.2-14) 4.8.2

```
static Map *decode_message(Message message)
{
    Map *map = message.content;
    map->blocks = (Color *)(map + 1);
}

static void *network_game_handler(void *ignore)
{
    Network_Message server_reply, out_msg = NET_OK;

    if(read_all(&server_reply, sizeof server_reply) == ERROR){
        if(error_callback != NULL)
            error_callback();

        close(sockfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    while(server_reply == NET_WAIT){
        if(write_all(&out_msg, sizeof out_msg) == ERROR){
            if(error_callback != NULL)
                error_callback();

            close(sockfd);
            return NULL;
        }
        if(read_all(&server_reply, sizeof server_reply) == ERROR){
            if(error_callback != NULL)
                error_callback();

            close(sockfd);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    if(server_reply == NET_ERROR){
        if(error_callback != NULL)
            error_callback();

        close(sockfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    if(server_reply == NET_START){
        out_msg = NET_START;
        if(write_all(&out_msg, sizeof out_msg) == ERROR){
            if(error_callback != NULL)
                error_callback();

            close(sockfd);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    else {
        if(error_callback != NULL)
            error_callback();

        close(sockfd);
        return NULL;
    }

    network_game_ready = 1;

    void *last_msg = NULL;
    Message current_msg;

    while(!game_handler_stop){
        out_msg = NET_DATA;
        if(write_all(&out_msg, sizeof out_msg) == ERROR)
            goto error;

        Message msg = encode_message((Map *)map);
        if(msg.content == NULL)
            goto error;

        if(send_message(msg) == ERROR){
            destroy_message(msg);
            goto error;
        }

        destroy_message(msg);

        if(read_all(&server_reply, sizeof server_reply) == ERROR)
            goto error;

        if(server_reply == NET_STOP){
            if(stop_callback != NULL)
                stop_callback();

            engine_set_adversary_map(NULL);
            free(last_msg);
            close(sockfd);
            return NULL;
        }

        if(server_reply == NET_ERROR)
            goto error;

        if(server_reply == NET_DATA)
            if((current_msg = receive_message()).content == NULL)
                goto error;

        ///////
        ////////    This line is where the problem happens
        ///////
        engine_set_adversary_map(decode_message(current_msg));
        printf("Setting adversary map to %zu\n", decode_message(current_msg));
        free(last_msg);
        last_msg = current_msg.content;
    }

    out_msg = NET_STOP;
    write_all(&out_msg, sizeof out_msg);

    engine_set_adversary_map(NULL);
    free(last_msg);
    close(sockfd);  
    return NULL;

    error:
    engine_set_adversary_map(NULL);
    if(error_callback != NULL)
        error_callback();

    free(last_msg);
    close(sockfd);
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, you are expecting to be able to process the return value of `decode_message()`, however, it fails to return anything.  GCC would warn you about the missing return statement if you enabled the `-Wreturn-type` warning. This is enabled if you use `-Wall`.

You probably intended to return `map`.

```
static Map *decode_message(Message message)
{
    Map *map = message.content;
    map->blocks = (Color *)(map + 1);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have no idea how I didn't see it. I should probably be sleeping.